# angular js dynamically generate link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angular js and want to make a very simple website, that does the following:
when clicking on a button, it will randomly generate a number, and if the number is odd, redirect to google, otherwise redirect to apple website. I have done the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="homeapp">
<head> ... all imports </head>
<body ng-controller="homeappCtrl"> 
  <a href="{{urlToPick}}">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and then in the controller.js, I have:

```
var homeapp= angular.module('homeappController', []);

homeappController.controller('homeappCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)%2==0)
      {$scope.urlToPick = 'http://google.ca';}
    else
      {$scope.urlToPick = 'http://apple.com';}
  }]);
```

The problem is that when I click on the link, the urlToPick is not resolved and therefore the link returns error. (the link url is something like xxx/{{urlToPick}} )

I guess I have done something wrong but please tell me where... Thanks!

Comment: what is problem here?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) when generates links dynamically... you can face some problems if your html is generated before your link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-app` and your `angular.module` definitions are different.

Change

```
var homeapp= angular.module('homeappController', []);
```

to

```
var homeapp= angular.module('homeapp', []);
```